# Getting image name into the database or is it even needed?

Tags: php

This is a two part question although my first delima is how do I get the file name to post to the database, or do I even need it to do that to call the correct image?

Currently, I have have a comment section that is posting and getting properly. I have an image that is moving to the correct directory folder. What I do not have is the file name posting to the database so that I can call on it to pull the correct image out of the directory. Every time I try to add something to post to the database I get an error for my image index being undefined.

Second I would like to be able to call on the image name from the database to pull that image into a thumbnail with the post. I am not entirely sure how to do this yet either.

my question is first off, how do I get the image to post to the database now that I have it moving correctly to the folder?

**HTML:**

```
<?php 
echo "<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='".setComments($conn)."'><br>
    <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='Anonymous'>
    <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'>

    Select a file:<br><input type='file' name='image' id='image'><br<br><br>
    Comment:<br> <textarea name='message'></textarea><br><br>
    <button type='submit' name='commentSubmit'>Upload</button><br><br><br>
    </form>";

getComments($conn); 
?>
```

**Function:**

```
<?php
function setComments($conn) {
    if (isset ($_POST['commentSubmit'])) {
        $uid = $_POST['uid'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (uid, date, message, images) values ('$uid','$date','$message','$file_name')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
}

if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    $errors= array();
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
    $tmp = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext =  end($tmp);
    $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png"."gif");

    if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
        $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG, GIF, or PNG file.";
    }

    if($file_size > 2097152) {
        $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
    }

        if(empty($errors)==true) {
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);
        echo "Successfully uploaded file!";
        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (uid, date, message, images) values ('$uid','$date','$message','$file_name')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }else{
        print_r($errors);
    }
}
```

Comment: Write `"uploads/".$file_name` to the DB. That should be where your image is stored. You also are open to SQL injections with this code. You should use parameterized queries. Also `"png"."gif"` is probably a typo.

Comment: Separate but why is the `action` set to `setComments`? The PHP is not available once the page loads.

Comment: do I write that into the insert statement in VALUES?

Comment: Yes, and add the column to the list of columns you are writing to. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php for how to parameterize.

Comment: setComments is a function on a separate PHP page that is included in the header of the HTML page

Comment: It is not there when the page loads so it will not execute like this. Look at the page when you load it `action` is empty, so it loads the same page, which might do what you want it to do, e.g. the `setcomments` would be executed, but its being executed before too.

Comment: must be writing it incorrectly. I'm getting a syntax error

Comment: Update the code and provide the error.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (uid, date, message,) values ('$uid','$date','$message','"uploads/".$file_name');  //this is giving me an error

Comment: Please use the `edit` option under the `tags`. Quickly looking though the `uid, date, message` needs the image column. I can't really tell if the PHP is correctly de-encapsulated and encapsulated. The SQL string also needs to be quoted... and if the file contains a quote this will fail, ideally and preferably you'll use a parameterized query.

Comment: Per your update the syntax highlighting alone here should show you the issue. The `uploads/` is static text just have the next the the single quote. Then concatenate the variable and concatenate a closing `'` so the SQL string closes.

Comment: All it tells me is that there is a syntax error

Comment: for one thing, the query belongs in the `if` not in the `else`. That else is for your print error. Store `$file_name` and not the folder name. That can be retrieved later with php.

Comment: so move the $sql and $result up above the else statement?

Comment: Yes, place the query and result right under `echo "Successfully uploaded file!";` and store the filename only at `'$file_name'`. So if the file uploads successfully, the query will run at the same time.

Comment: well it broke the uid, name, and message now

Comment: it's saying they are undefined now

Comment: that's because your files stuff is outside your custom function. Put everything inside your function and move the closing brace for it, at the end of your script. If @chris85 wants to keep going with this, great. I have a few things to tend to right now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think I've already looked at too much code today. I missed the SQL on the wrong side of the `}`.

Comment: got all of that working now. it is posting to the folder and the database. Thank you very much...next hurdle ....the get function ...comments working now need to call on the image in the database to create the thumbnail